# Google Sheets: Take the number, search for closest lower number in column, show info from 2 rows located left from founded number

Tags: google-sheets, formula

I got number 4677,414 in column **F**

And a column **E** with 19780 rows, contained numbers from 4000 to 20000

Column **C** contains time, column **D** – date

---

I need formula, to search >= closest number to 4677,414, for example it will be a 4715,30:

And show column C (time) and column D (date) content, from the founded row.

[Example screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hj4U6.png)

Comment: use filter and sort and array constrain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your number is in cell F2 since you didn't say where it was, this might work:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(F2,SORT({E2:E,C2:D}),{2,3}))
```

If you're in certain countries in Europe you might need this instead:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(F2;SORT({E2:E\C2:D});{2\3}))
```

Comment: Sorry but it gave me back 2 cells: 0,08333333333 and 43426

Comment: Idea was it got to show info 16:00 and 09.10.2017 from row #9 (I also added a screenshot to the question)

Comment: Just format those numbers. Menu>Format>Number>Time. And then Menu>Format>Number>Date for the second one.

Answer (score 0):

put this formula in F3 or under 4677,414:

```
=array_constrain(sort(filter(E2:E, E2:E>=F2),1,true),1,1)
```